# Cloning only one git project subdirectory through bower.json

Tags: git, bower, subdirectory

I try to get only one folder from a private repo with `bower install`.

I want to do something like this, `src` (is in the root folder) is the subdirectory I need:

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-component" : "git@git.mywebsite.com:web-components/my-component/src.git"
}
```

This works fine and clones the whole project:

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-component" : "git@git.mywebsite.com:web-components/my-component.git"
}
```

Is there a way to do this? I've read about `svn` and  `git submodules`, but I'm not sure if this is what I need.

I've also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only) but I can't figure out how to use it.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bower is a package manager and nothing to do with the GIT.

You need to check the sparse checkout option in git.
Execute the following command in the terminal

```
git config core.sparseCheckout true
```

Now define the files/folders you want to check out in the file sparse-checkout which can be found inside .git/info/sparse-checkout.

Now execute a git pull.

Check the [Sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree) section for more info.